# How to align items in HTML using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, text-align

I want my items to be placed in a specific order, so that the **title** (The header with the copyright paragraph) to be centered in the middle of the page my About section to not fill up half of my page ... I've tried using flex-basis so that I can give every item a specific width but didn't seem to work, any ideas? Here is the code for the footer part, I have this problem for both navbar and footer, but I guess if it will work for one it will work in general
Also PM : I don't know why most of the html code dosen't show with snippet , here is an image of how it looks https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZepw.jpg

HTML CODE :

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
  align-self: start;

}

.bg-dark,
.btn-dark {
  background-color: var(--dark-color);
  color: #fff;
}
.footer .box a{

  margin: 0 5px;
}
.lead {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.py-1 {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<footer class="footer bg-dark ">
    <div class="container flex lead py-1">
       <div class="box">
           <h1>About</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis voluptatum vel praesentium molestias consectetur ea consequuntur a quidem vitae iste?</p>
       </div> 
       <div class="box">
        <h1>CarolandHousing</h1>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2021</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="features.html">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="docs.html">Docs</a></li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
     </div>
</footer>
```

[Working Domo](https://jsfiddle.net/6grukdex/5/)

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand what you want to acheive, an image with some blocks would be great

Comment: I added an image to the question , as you can see in the navbar the title is not centerd with the page , and in the footer , the about section is way to big with horrible aligment of the rest items

Comment: @VlAdTbK: Sorry to say this, but you haven't framed your question properly :) The specifications are not clear :)

Comment: I want to make the things look like you understood I think , not like in the image ( haveing the about section smaller , the title centered etc...) but thanks to an answer bellow I managed to get it done... Now I have one more question https://imgur.com/VKn0LO0 , How can I make the Home Features and Docs text align in row while the icons stay below ?

Comment: There's a bunch of good articles and tutorials about aligning items with flexbox. This is just one: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

Comment: Ah ok thank you for the tip , I am still new to html , still trying to figure it out

Comment: Your markup and class names look like they've been taken from Bootstrap 4.x, but you're not mentioning it in your question. (except perhaps in *"I don't know why most of the html code dosen't show with snippet"* which might be because you haven't loaded Bootstrap CSS). What you're trying to achieve is trivial using Bootstrap. So, are you using Bootstrap in your project or not? Because if you do, it changes a lot (the bigger part of Bootstrap means CSS which affects how most of your elements look like).

Comment: Nope , the names are similar to bootstrap ones but I created them by myself , I used them as model so I can edit them if I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the updated code according to your requirements which are as follows:-

1. All three columns in flex take equal width (`33%`)
2. Optional: Links removing list style and right align for better UI

```css
.flex {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
  align-self: start;
  
}

.flex-basis-3{
  flex-basis: 33%
}

.text-center{
  text-align: center
}

.text-right{
  text-align: right
}

.no-list{
  list-style: none;
}

.bg-dark,
.btn-dark {
  background-color: var(--dark-color);
  color: #000;
}
.footer .box a{
  margin: 0;
}
.lead {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.py-1 {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<footer class="footer bg-dark ">
    <div class="container-fluid flex lead py-1">
       <div class="box flex-basis-3">
           <h1>About</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis voluptatum vel praesentium molestias consectetur ea consequuntur a quidem vitae iste?</p>
       </div> 
       <div class="box flex-basis-3 text-center">
        <h1>CarolandHousing</h1>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2021</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box flex-basis-3 text-right">
            <div class="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
               <span><a href="index.html">Home</a></span>
               <span><a href="features.html">Features</a></span>
               <span><a href="docs.html">Docs</a></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Yep worked like it needed to , but now I have another question about how the aligment of Home Features and Docs ... How can I align them in a row while the icons stay below them ? https://imgur.com/VKn0LO0

Comment: Hey @VlAdTbK, I have updated the code with links and alignment as per your requirement

Comment: Yeah it worked for all the aligment except for the Home Features Docs part ... How can I make them show in a Row ? I tried flex-direction : row ; but dosen't seem to put them how I want ... any ideas ?

Comment: Hey @VlAdTbK, I want to understand your requirements better. You want to show the nav links(home, features and docs) in column layout like facebook and instagram icons below? Currently home, features and docs links are shown as rows.

Comment: Aa from my pov and from the snippet they don't , they are in column https://imgur.com/52OA2DN and I don't know why ... And after that if you could help me with another problem I will be grateful becouse right now I am very confused

Comment: Hey @VlAdTbK, I have updated the design of links as you needed. In smallers screens it might come into next line because of space issues as we have given fixed width in all three sections. Please have a look

Comment: Good to hear you are satisfied with the layout of final code. Can you please approve my answer so that it can also help other devs who come to seek solution having similar layout issue in their code.

Comment: Of course of course , and if you could help me with something else on chat I would be gratefull ( if you have some spare time )

Comment: Sure, Please describe your problem in same question or separate one(share link here)

Comment: I've posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65562748/cant-proprely-align-text-with-animation-in-html , for a more detalied explination we could chat

Comment: did you saw the question ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Please give me sometime to see the problem and after that will reply to you with appropriate answer

Comment: So no answers to that question ? I see no one seems to know something about it

Comment: Hey @VlAdTbK, Link is not working anymore, it seems like question has been removed

Comment: Actually no , I've reopened it becouse I tought I solved it but no , still the same issue ... So if you have some spare time can you give it a look ?